# How do I make a sum function output all the number it added up?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make this program output all the number it added up?
For example: User enters 4, 10: prints 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 49

Here is my code:

```
def absolute_sum(first_num, second_num):
    sum = 0
    if second_num > first_num:
        for i in range(first_num, second_num+1):
            sum += i
    elif first_num > second_num:
        for i in range(second_num, first_num+1):
            sum += i
    else: sum = first_num*2
    return sum

first_num = int(input("Enter first number: "))  
second_num = int(input("Enter second number: "))
...
sum_string = absolute_sum(first_num, second_num)

print("+{}+\n|{}|\n+{}+".format(len(sum_string)*'-', sum_string, len(sum_string)*'-'))
```

Comment: can second_num be bigger than first_num?

Comment: @GilseungAhn Yes it can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage `max` and `min` to ensure that the range always goes in ascending order.

You can then generate the range from your lower_bound and upper_bound + 1. (Remember `range` is upper_bound non-inclusive)

Using the `join` function in `str`, you can make your range separated by " + ".

Lastly use the `sum` function to get the total value.

```py
first_num = int(input("Enter first number: "))
second_num = int(input("Enter second number: "))

numbers = range(min(first_num, second_num), max(first_num, second_num) + 1)

print(f'{" + ".join([str(n) for n in numbers])} = {sum(numbers)}')
```

*Per request without any format strings or list comprehension.

```py
first_num = int(input("Enter first number: "))
second_num = int(input("Enter second number: "))

lower_bound = min(first_num, second_num)
upper_bound = max(first_num, second_num)
total = 0

# Handle All But Last Value
for number in range(lower_bound, upper_bound):
    print(number, end=" + ")
    total += number

# Handle Last Value
print(upper_bound, end=" = ")
total += upper_bound

# Handle Total
print(total)
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without the .join function and without the f' strings? Thanks

Comment: @JonathanMiller Can I ask why you want to avoid those?

Comment: That's a bad philosophy. Those (`join` and `f-strings`) are very basic and important concepts in Python. Avoiding to learn and sticking with stuff you know will not advance you with your programming. You should always strive to learn new and better ways of doing stuff @JonathanMiller

Answer (score 0):

you can use `str.join` method to get all the integer together and have a common join character between all off them.

```
def absolute_sum(first_num, second_num):
    if first_num==second_num:
        return 2*first_num

    first_num, second_num = min(first_num, second_num), max(first_num, second_num)
    total = list(range(first_num, second_num+1))
    sum_ = sum(total)
    val = ' + '.join([(str(i) if i>=0 else ('('+str(i)+')')) for i in total ])

    return f"{val} = {sum_}"
```